# Rally - Dashboard Apps -Defect App Query

Tags: rally

I'm trying to create a very basic query in the Defect app (Submitted by = my Name) however when I save, the following message is returned:

Could not parse: Unknown operator "By"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use camel case instead of spaces in fields names when using the Rally Web Services API (WSAPI), so in this case the field should be called SubmittedBy.

You can see all the available fields on Defect here in the documentation:
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/objectModel.sp#Defect